# Delete rows from table but keep a given number

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Using mysql, how do I delete all rows from a table, but keep, say, 200 records?

The obvious approach is to count them, do some arithmetic, and delete the right number. But does mysql has some builtin function that does it in one delete query?

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete ALL but x amount of records or are you saying you want to Delete ALL but backup the records elsewhere?

Comment: @Josh I want to delete ALL but x records. They stay in the table afterwards.

Comment: Which 200 records should not be deleted? Do you have a datetime column and want to keep the 200 newest records or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete using a condition:

```
delete from YourTable
where YourSequentialID > 200
```

However your sequential could have gaps, so you would not have *exactly* 200 rows. So what you can do is working on your condition.

Find the records you want to keep (say the first 200) and delete everything else:

```
delete from YourTable 
where id not in
(
select ID 
from YourTable
LIMIT 200
)
```

I know, that can be slow. But that's not a production query, it's just a clean up query. You can live with having to run it only once.